# How to go about extracting data from a class name using selenium with slight variation? but the class name may have slight variations

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

Lets just say I am looking at this html on a webpage below:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="a1"></div>
    <div class="a2"></div>
    <div class="a3"></div>
    <div class="a4"></div>
    <div class="a5"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to print out the class names within class box and it could range from a1 to a5

I am unsure about how to go about doing it

Comment: <div class= "box ">
        <div class = a1></div>
        </div>


    

Html which shouldhave been in post <div class= "box ">
     <div class = a5></div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
locator = '//div[@class="box"] div'
list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, locator)
For div in list:
    print(div.getAttribute('class'))
```